# Linux System Call Flow Sequence

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

I had a question regarding the deep working of Linux.

Lets say a multi-threaded process is being executed in the CPU. We will have a thread which is being executed on the CPU in such a case. At a more broader picture we will have the corresponding page belonging to the Process being loaded in the RAM for execution.

Lets say the thread makes a system call. I am a bit unclear on the workings after this. The Interrupt will generate a call. One of my questions is who will answer this call?

Lets say that the system has m:n user level thread to kernel level thread mapping, I am assuming that the corresponding Kernel Level Thread will answer this call.

So the Kernel will lookup the Interrupt Vector Table and get the routine which needs to be executed. My next question is which stack will be used in the execution of the Interrupt? Will it be the Kernel Thread's Stack or the User level Thread's Stack? (I am assuming that it will be the Kernel Thread's Stack.)

Coming back to the flow of the program lets say the operation is opening a file using `fopen`. The subsequent question I have is  how will the jump from the ISR to System Call take place? Or is our ISR mapped to a System Call?

Also at a more broader picture when the Kernel Thread is being executed I am assuming that the "OS region" on the RAM will be used to house the pages which are executing the System Call.

Again looking at it from a different angle (Hope your still with me) finally I am assuming that the corresponding Kernel Thread is being handled by the CPU Scheduler where in a context switch would have happened from the User Level Thread to the corresponding Kernel Level Thread when the `fopen` System Call was being answered.

I have made a lot of assumptions and it would be absolutely fantastic if anyone could clear the doubts or at least guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Would you mind reformatting the wall of text so that it's a little easier to read? Thanks.

Comment: Also, read several books on Linux programming. You first need to understand the application side, e.g. http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ then you need to understand the kernel's point of view, and many books also exist...

Comment: Hi Basile, I have read multiple books on Linux and they almost give me the same information. I am however unable to stitch everything together. How the entire procedure works in Real Time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Note: I work predominately with ARM machines so some of these things might be ARM specific. Also, I'm going to try and simplify it as much as I can. Feel free to correct anything that might be wrong or oversimplified.*

> Lets say the thread makes a system call. I am a bit unclear on the workings after this. The Interrupt will generate a call. One of my questions is who will answer this call?

Usually, the processor will start executing at some predetermined location in kernel mode. The kernel will save the current process state and look at the userspace registers to determine which system call was requested and dispatch that to the correct system call handler.

> So the Kernel will lookup the Interrupt Vector Table and get the routine which needs to be executed. My next question is which stack will be used in the execution of the Interrupt? Will it be the Kernel Thread's Stack or the User level Thread's Stack? (I am assuming that it will be the Kernel Thread's Stack.)

I'm pretty sure it will switch to a kernel stack. There would be some pretty severe security problems with information leaks if they used the userspace stack.

> Coming back to the flow of the program lets say the operation is opening a file using fopen. The subsequent question I have is how will the jump from the ISR to System Call take place? Or is our ISR mapped to a System Call?

`fopen()` is actually a libc function and not a system call itself. It may (and in most cases will) call the `open()` syscall in its implementation though.

So, the process (roughly) is:

1. Userspace calls `fopen()`
2. `fopen` performs a system call to `open()`
3. This triggers some sort of exception or interrupt. In response, the processor switches into a more privileged mode and starts executing at some preset location in the kernel.
4. Kernel determines what kind of interrupt and exception it is and handles it appropriately. In our case, it will be a system call.
5. Kernel determines which system call is being requested by reading the userspace registers and extracts any arguments and passes it to the appropriate handler.
6. Handler runs.
7. Kernel puts any return code into userspace registers.
8. Kernel transfers execution back to where the exception occured.

> Also at a more broader picture when the Kernel Thread is being executed I am assuming that the "OS region" on the RAM will be used to house the pages which are executing the System Call.

Pages don't execute anything :) Usually, in Linux, any address mapped above 0xC0000000 belongs to the kernel.

> Again looking at it from a different angle (Hope your still with me) finally I am assuming that the corresponding Kernel Thread is being handled by the CPU Scheduler where in a context switch would have happened from the User Level Thread to the corresponding Kernel Level Thread when the fopen System Call was being answered.

With a preemptive kernel, threads effectively aren't discriminated against. With my understanding, a new thread isn't created for the purpose of servicing a system call - it just runs in the same thread from which the system call was requested in, except in kernel mode.

That means a thread that is in kernel mode servicing a system call can be scheduled out just the same as any other thread. Hence, this is where you hear about 'userspace context' when developing for the kernel. It means it's executing in kernel mode on a usermode thread.

It's a little difficult to explain this so I hope I got it right.

Comment: I have a small follow up question. In your last paragraph you have mentioned that a thread will be in two modes that is User and Kernel Mode.

So as per my understanding when a system call is made the Thread goes from User mode to Kernel mode.

My question is how does this fit into the Threading Models supported by Linux such as 1;1, 1:n and m:n threads. So if we have 1:n and we have 2 threads when both of them make a system call at the same time the other will be blocked until the servicing of this thread is done?

Comment: Depends what kind of system call. If they're completely unrelated, they wouldn't block at all, they'd just run in parallel. If they're both trying to access the same resource in the kernel, it'll depend on how that resource is locked in the kernel. It could mean one thread is blocked until the other finishes accessing the resource.